# Cannot invoke because "this.roleRepository" is null

Tags: sql, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I am getting an error when I try to run my Java spring boot application . Please find below the code snippets and the error I am getting.

setAdmin() method in Controller class

```
 @PutMapping("/update/{id}")
    //@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
    public ResponseEntity<User> setAdmin(@PathVariable("id") Long id, @RequestBody User user) {
        Optional<User> userData = userRepository.findById(id);
        Optional<Role> adminRole = roleRepository.findByName(ERole.ROLE_ADMIN);
        Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
        roles.add(adminRole.get());
        if (userData.isPresent()) {
            User _user = userData.get();
            _user.setRoles(roles);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(userRepository.save(_user), HttpStatus.OK);
        } else {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
    }
```

---

RoleRepository interface

```
public interface RoleRepository extends JpaRepository<Role, Long> {
   Optional<Role> findByName(ERole name);

}
```

---

ERole enum

```
public enum ERole {
    ROLE_USER,
    ROLE_MODERATOR,
    ROLE_ADMIN
}
```

---

The error

```
erreur:
Cannot invoke "com.jwt.authentification.Repository.RoleRepository.findByName(com.jwt.authentification.Domaine.ERole)" because "this.roleRepository" is null
```

Comment: May I see where you are instantiating the this.roleRepository

Answer (score -3):

Most probably you have to instantiate the repository using the @Autowired annotation.

Comment: thank you  , it is ok  but methode not work . without erreur

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).